# deploy the same application multiple times on tomcat

Tags: tomcat, deployment, multiple-instances

I want to deploy the same applications multiple times on the same tomcat instance for different "customers".
Since im not really experienced with tomcat and other application servers i dont have a point to start.
When i simply generate war files like app1.war and app2.war (based on the same code) it doesnt work, bc the war files are named diferent but the project is still called the same, so tomcat is confused i think. So i really dont know where to start.
Another starting point is to have multiple tomcat sessions for each application but i have a feeling that this is a waste of performance...?
I would appriciate if you could point me to the right direction.

Edit: Im using different databases for the different war files. I think that is the problem. How could i chaqnge that?
Cheers,
m

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a tomcat settings, but a workaround, but has some advantages that  you only need to modify the application once for all the users...

You can use an ID to identify the user that is accessing your application.

Then in your application you will use a different database based on the userID...

Comment: Thanks. Thats basically what i did. I have some configurations files for the different customers. With every request from the client side i send the id with the request and the session Factory handler handles it and fowards me to the right database. Also Hibernate 4 has exactlz this use case implemented now..