# How to deploy the same Grails application twice in Tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, grails, deployment, war

If I deploy the same Grails application twice in Tomcat (ie myApplication_first.war, myApplication_second.war), Tomcat can't deploy the WAR files, reproducible. 
It complains that class XYZ already exists in the TEMP folder (which is true, due to the previous deployment).
So to change the global Tomcat TEMP folder won't make any sense since both projects would use the same folder again anyhow.

I know in general how to deploy an application twice, but not in Grails context, due it manages already a lot of stuff on it's own.

Is there any way to realize this plan?

We use the Grails version 1.3.7.

I searched for a lot of possible solutions, but none fit to my needs.

- Deploying on multiple Tomcat instances
- Deploying only one application and use some unique identifier to identify the mandatory/client for providing individual data sources and stuff. (See [deploy the same application multiple times on tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8092505/deploy-the-same-application-multiple-times-on-tomcat))
- Replace Tomcat by another application server

One approach that came to my mind but still seems little bit weird to me, is, to change the packages of all classes on the fly during the deployment (with ANT or s.th. like that). So that they can not collide in the Tomcat TEMP folder. 
Might this be potentially a solution? 
Is it even possible in an elegant way?

Kind regards,
Christopher

Answer (score 0):

I have similar situation and my solution was to "transform" the application into grails plugin and then create more (I had 6) application, which used this plugin and in each application I adapted the configuration (DataSource, etc.). Even if nearly 100% of the final WAR files were the same, it worked correctly.

Did you also try the TomCat vhosting?

Comment: Hello Tom, thanks for your reply.

Let me get this straight:
You moved mostly all of your code into a separate plugin, and this plugin gets included by all your other (though similar) projects? 

Tomcat vhost:
Wouldn't this be a layer too late?

Comment: First part: yes, correct, I moved all the code to the plugin and then create separate application with this plugin installed, different was just the dabatase configuration (it was a CMS app ... to make it clear ;-) )

Second part: well, you can use both Apache and TomCat vhosting, if you want, it is not a technical problem. But with the vhost in TomCat, I was wondering if this can help to solve your problem now, before the moving of the code into the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to deploy two nearly identical grails 1.3.7 applications onto the same tomcat 7 instance without problems. The second app was basically a clone of the first with only some minor changes to a few source files. Each app had a different WAR name (looks like you are already doing that), and I also ensured that grails.app.context in Config.groovy was different for each app. I believe tomcat had some issues with underscores in WAR files names in some earlier versions, but I don't know if its still the case with more recent versions. Try using different WAR names without the underscore, and editing grails.app.context to match.

Comment: Thanks. I gonna try renaming the WARs and varifying the context.
Maybe I can also try to test with Tomcat 7.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the [tomcat manager application](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html). It has a reload option that might solve your issue.

Some companies disable the manager (additional webapp that comes with the tomcat distribution). I understand the security concerns, but this can be addresses, the manager definately simplifies app deployment.

Comment: The manager won't help us since we use auto-deployment via Hudson/Jenkins.
But thanks anyways.